# I have written apex code to single email trigger seems perfect but i didn't get any email notification

Tags: apex, trigger, email

I have written apex code to single email trigger seems perfect but i didn't get any email notification to my email do i have to do any settings or any thing wrong in code]? here is my code

```
trigger Process on sample__c (before insert, before update) {

    for(sample__c sam: Trigger.New){

            if(sam.SendCol__c =='Send'){

                if(sam.Send_Email__c !=null){


                        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                        //create new single email 

                        String emailAddr = sam.Send_Email__c;
                        //getting the email address and seller name 

                        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {emailAddr};
                        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
                        //Set whome the email is to be sent

                       mail.setReplyTo('harrythefox@gmail.com');
                       //Set reply to email address

                       mail.setSenderDisplayName('ABCCompany');
                       //Set senders name display 
                        mail.setSubject('Saleforce alert to');
                        //Set the email subject 

                        mail.setPlainTextBody('This is a test email message to');
                        mail.setHtmlBody('This is test body message: <b>');
                        //set the email body with html style 

                        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
                        //send the single email to the seller


                }
            }


    }

}
```

Comment: have you try to put debug log inside just in case the condition is not fulfilled ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to add below code, to send mail:

```
mail.setReplyTo('your mail id to whom you send the mail');
mail.setSenderDisplayName('Sender display name');
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer bro  i have added both codes after 'mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);' but still i didn't receive any email to my email address. I also done this
Setup -> EmailAdministration -> Deliverability-> Access Level ='All Email' setting

Comment: Still it's not working!!!

Comment: You try to do any hard-coded valid email address in *emailAddr* variable and run. As your code looks correct. Did you debug the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Please check Setup -> EmailAdministration -> Deliverability-> Access Level ='All Email'

Comment: Thank you for your answer bro i have added both codes after 'mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);' but still i didn't receive any email to my email address. I also done this Setup -> EmailAdministration -> Deliverability-> Access Level ='All Email' setting

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve sending of email with Workflow.
Create a Workflow with following criteria and make sure 'Send_Email__c' is email field type, so that we can select Recipient Type as Email Field for Email alert

[image: Create a Workflow]

[image: Select Email Field as Recipient type]

Comment: Bro i have tried that as well it's not working

Comment: Request for Email logs files Setup -> Monitor -> Logs -> Email Log files. Use this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_logs_format.htm&language=en) for referring logs.